# Documents in textarea

Tags: php, pdf, textarea, sanitize

I have a contact form on a web site; just ordinary html in a php page:
    *`<textarea name="message" id ="message" rows="10" cols="30">  </textarea>`*
I didn't yet sanitize the input as I figured that it was only going to be sent as an email anyway...
Interestingly, the spammers have found a way of attaching/inserting what appears to be a .PDF doc to the message.
My two questions are:
1. How are they doing this? I can't seem to find a way to insert a document or attach a document to a message in a textarea, so how can they?
2. Will sanitizing the input with strip_tags and htmlspecialchars stop them doing it?
Thanks.
Edit:
Thanks for getting back to me - here is a screen shot of one of the emails; as you say, gmail seems to be picking up the url:
[image: image of spam email]

I don't suppose I should click on that link, hey?

Answer (score 1):

Without more detail, I can only guess.  `<textarea>` does not allow attaching a file, only text (string of any characters).  It would allow including a URL in the text.  If you send this URL-containing text via email, your email reader likely recognizes the URL-string and converts it to a clickable link.  So, strictly speaking, the PDF file is not appended to the email, but a link to the PDF is.

If this is the case, sanitizing for HTML *tags* won't work but sanitizing for URLs will.